# setting eclipse with minGW compiler to use C99

Tags: c, eclipse, mingw, c99

Could someone outline how to use c99 when my c-programs compile? I cannot use the for(int i = 0...) loop without it. Note - all the answers I have found are either outdated, or for the cygwin compiler.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the project build settings set `-std=c99` in the "Other flags" text box.